# What are the security support statuses of derivatives?

Tags: security, derivatives

I have only a quick question. Does Kubuntu, Xubuntu and others has the same level of security like the plain Ubuntu? I mean security for the desktop environment, because I know that for others it has, because it is based on Ubuntu. And also, do I need to worry about it, as I am not an advanced user? (not beginner, but I'm not extremely good at IT as others :D )
 Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is the same across all supported derivatives of Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.).

See also:

http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features

Comment: A more detailed response would be that the derivatives use the same Ubuntu repositories than Ubuntu itself. e.g. Kubuntu uses _main_, _universe_, _restricted_ and _multiverse_. So all updates to the repositories will be available to the derivatives.